# Status code 405 when distribute android app to AppCenter on AzureDevops pipelines

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

​Hi!

I have a problem when i try distribute an Android app using pipelines. I have a simple task for distribute but always return **405 error**.

**This is my task:**

```
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'AppCenterConnection'
    appSlug: '$(APPCENTER_ANDROID_DISTRIBUTION_SLUG)'
    appFile: '**/*.apk'
    symbolsOption: 'Android'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'Build $(Build.BuildNumber). Development version'
    destinationType: 'groups'
    distributionGroupId: '$(APPCENTER_ANDROID_DISTRIBUTION_GROUP)'
```

​
Also i try with Releases but i have same error.

**Release Task:**
[image: Release]

**Response:**
[image: Response]

All variables are define and the apk generated works fine. If i download artifact and upload manually on AppCenter all works fine. But the task doesn't work.

My appcenter url : https://appcenter.ms/users/mbarrera-plainconcepts/apps/FirstDays.Android

**Variables:**
[image: Variables]

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: For troubleshooting, could you try [distributing using the App Center command-line interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/uploading#distributing-using-the-app-center-command-line-interface) to check if it can be distributed successfully with cli?

Comment: I also have this issue, did you get a fix?

Comment: Not at the moment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
    This configuration worked for me.

My Version:
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
inputs:
serverEndpoint: 'myAPPcenter'
appSlug: 'ORG/application'
appFile: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/*.apk'
symbolsOption: 'Android'
releaseNotesOption: 'file'
releaseNotesFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CHANGELOG.md'
destinationType: 'groups'
isSilent: false
```

Comment: Did you have the 405 issue with any configuration? How does this fix the original issue?